# Can't start Rails Server - Could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
pallav@pallav-System-Product-Name:~/Workspace/blog$ rails server

/home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/uglifier-2.4.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/uglifier-2.4.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
  from /home/pallav/Workspace/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
  from /home/pallav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

pallav@pallav-System-Product-Name:~/Workspace/blog$
```

It didn't worked even i did this:

> $ gem install execjs

My Gemfile contains this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dDBDBRc2_4-dFDI0dMLBfLg-BVWId0diH-Xsb2CZhD8/edit

Comment: If you're on a modern macOS, try upgrading `execjs` gem to 2.8.0+.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a Javascript runtime. Execjs is in fact a wrapper around various runtimes you could use. You still need to install one of them. Several systems already bring a usable one (MacOS and Windows). On others, you need to install one.

In the error description, it pointed you towards https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme which describes several of the supported runtimes (Hint: Always read error messages!). In your `Gemfile`, you'll notice that there is the `therubyracer` gem referenced (but commented out). It is one of the supported runtimes.

Thus, you could just uncomment this gem, run `bundle install` and be set.

Answer (score 16):

You need a Javascript runtime installed, like [Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) for example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64

Comment: For Ubuntu and Debian, use `apt-get` instead of `brew`